# HTML/Javascript Openweather app info not showing

Tags: javascript, html

I am a javascript beginner and trying to make a little openweather app. It's very simple but I don't get click button and show temperature.

Thanks everybody :)

HTML code to insert info:

```js
let cities = document.querySelector("#cities");
let selectedCityID = cities.options[cities.selectedIndex].value;
let selectedCityName = cities.options[cities.selectedIndex].text;

let button = document.querySelector(".button");
let name = document.querySelector(".name");
let description = document.querySelector(".description");
let temperature = document.querySelector(".temperature");


button.addEventListener("click", getWeatherData);

function getWeatherData() {
  let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open('GET', 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?id=' + selectedCityID + '&appid=efe55429af07a5a65c4c7ebbfa33c8fe', true);
  request.onreadystatechange = function(e) {
    if (request.readyState == 4) {
      if (request.readyState == 200) {
        let response = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
        if (response) {
          let tempCelsius = (response.main.temp - 32) / 1.8000;
          showInfo(tempCelsius);
        }
      } else {
        console.log("Error");
      }
    }
    request.send(null);
  }
}

function showInfo(temperature) {
  document.querySelector(".name").innerHTML = selectedCityName;
  document.querySelector(".description").innerHTML = "El tiempo en conversión en grados Celsius es:";
  document.querySelector(".temperature").innerHTML = `Temperatura: ${temperature} ºC`;
}
```

```html
<select name="city" id="cities">
  <option value="2514256">Málaga</option>
  <option value="2517117">Granada</option>
  <option value="3117735">Madrid</option>
  <option value="3117814">Lugo</option>
  <option value="3128760">Barcelona</option>
</select>
<button class="button">CONSULTAR</button>

<div class="showWeather">
  <h1 class="name"></h1>
  <p class="description"></p>
  <span class="temperature"></span>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

Comment: Have you tried if he goes inside your showInfo function?

Comment: Console doesn't show anything so I suppose getWeatherData is not working good.

Comment: you didn't declare cities!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare cities like

```
const cities = document.getElementById('cities')
```

or

```
const cities = document.querySelector('#cities')
```

Edited

```js
let button = document.querySelector(".button");

button.addEventListener("click",function() {
 
  let cities = document.querySelector("#cities");
  let selectedCityID = cities.options[cities.selectedIndex].value;
  let selectedCityName = cities.options[cities.selectedIndex].text;

  let name = document.querySelector(".name");
  let description = document.querySelector(".description");
  let temperature = document.querySelector(".temperature");

  let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open('GET', 'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?id=' + selectedCityID + '&appid=efe55429af07a5a65c4c7ebbfa33c8fe');
  request.send();
  
  request.onload = function(){
    if(request.status !== 200){
      console.error('response status is: '+ request.status)
    }else{
      let response = JSON.parse(request.response);
          console.log(response);
                if (response) {
                  // list is an array
                    let tempCelsius = (response.list[0].main.temp - 32) / 1.8000;
                    showInfo(tempCelsius);
                }
    }
  }
  
  function showInfo(temperature) {
    document.querySelector(".name").innerHTML = selectedCityName;
    document.querySelector(".description").innerHTML = "El tiempo en conversión en grados Celsius es:";
    document.querySelector(".temperature").innerHTML = `Temperatura: ${temperature} ºC`;
}
  
})

function showInfo(temperature) {
  document.querySelector(".name").innerHTML = selectedCityName;
  document.querySelector(".description").innerHTML = "El tiempo en conversión en grados Celsius es:";
  document.querySelector(".temperature").innerHTML = `Temperatura: ${temperature} ºC`;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The request is never sended because you are calling `request.send(null)` function inside `request.onreadystatechange`:

```
function getWeatherData() {
  let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open('GET', 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?id=' + selectedCityID + '&appid=efe55429af07a5a65c4c7ebbfa33c8fe', true);
  request.onreadystatechange = function(e) {
    if (request.readyState == 4) {
      if (request.status == 200) { //--> status
        let response = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
        if (response) {
          let tempCelsius = (response.main.temp - 32) / 1.8000;
          showInfo(tempCelsius);
        }
      } else {
        console.log("Error");
      }
    }
  }
  request.send(null); //--> You need to call it here, outside of onreadystatechange
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried that ( declare cities and request.send position) and now console log shows me Error Message of the else statement:

```
let selectedCityID = cities.options[cities.selectedIndex].value;
let selectedCityName = cities.options[cities.selectedIndex].text;

let button = document.querySelector(".button");
let name = document.querySelector(".name");
let description = document.querySelector(".description");
let temperature = document.querySelector(".temperature");


button.addEventListener("click", getWeatherData);

function getWeatherData() {
    let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('GET', 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?id=' + selectedCityID + '&appid=efe55429af07a5a65c4c7ebbfa33c8fe', true);
    request.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (request.readyState == 4) {
            if (request.readyState == 200) {
                let response = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
                if (response) {
                    let tempCelsius = (response.main.temp - 32) / 1.8000;
                    showInfo(tempCelsius);
                }
            } else {
                console.log("Error");
            }
        }
    }
    request.send(null);
}

function showInfo(temperature) {
    document.querySelector(".name").innerHTML = selectedCityName;
    document.querySelector(".description").innerHTML = "El tiempo en conversión en grados Celsius es:";
    document.querySelector(".temperature").innerHTML = `Temperatura: ${temperature} ºC`;
}
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/07nE2.png)

Comment: Should be request.status == 200